# populate dropdown list from a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, n-tier-architecture, business-objects

In an attempt of building a 3-tier architecture c# asp.net application, I've started building a class that is database which is used for the connecting to the database, another class that is City which has a method for each column in the table cities, and a Cities class in which I have the GetCities method that creates a list of City objects and then use the DataSource wizard to set the control to use the data from GetCities(). 
All I get is blanks in the dropdown list. Any idea why?

```
        public List<City> GetCities()
    {
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        Database db = new Database();
        SqlConnection conn = db.GetConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CITIES";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            City c = new City(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1).ToString());
            cities.Add(c);
        }

        db.CloseConnection();
        return cities;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: The problem is in the code that you have not shared! How do you populate the list? **What is the code that WIZARD generates?**

Comment: Your code for filling the list looks fine.  The problem must be how you are binding to the drop down list (maybe you can post that)?  I know you said you used a wizard, which would be the first place I would look to see what it is doing.  Also, you are closing your database connection, but if there is an exception, it won't be closed.  Either use a try/finally or in your call to ExecuteReader indicate that the connection will close when the reader is closed and use a using() statement for your reader.

Comment: the WIZARD I'm talking about is accessed while clicking "choose data source" on the DropDownList and the a window pops that prompts me for a data source. I choose new Data Source and then another window pops from which I chose Object from a list that includes "Access db, SQL db, Entity" etc. After which another window pops prompting to choose the object, which in my case is Cities. Next > Choose a method, which in my case is GetCities().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resided in the City class which after a close inspection I've realised that the constructor was assigning the parameter received incorrectly. It's now working. Thanks!

```
public class City
{
    int id;
    string name;

    public City(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the DataTextField, DataValueField properties, and call DataBind?

---

At this point I would try to get the concept working as simply as possible, and then start adding things back in until you locate the problem.  Start with a brand new page, add a DropDownList but don't touch the data source or change any properties, go directly into the codebehind and add this in Page_Load:

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataSource = new[] {
    new { ID = 1, Name = "Alice" },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Mike" },
    new { ID = 3, Name = "John" }
};
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Does it work?  It does for me.  Then try to change DataValueField, DataTextField, and DataSource to work with your customer list.  Is it broken now?  Then you know the problem is in the customer list somewhere, not with the way you're binding the data.

Comment: I really don't know 'cause I never use the wizard, but is it really helping in this case or just adding an unneeded layer?  I've always just set DataTextField, DataValueField, DataSource = someList, and called DataBind.

Comment: good point J.D., but even putting the following in the page_load the result is the same: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cities c = new Cities();

        ddlistLocation.DataSource = c.GetCities();
        ddlistLocation.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlistLocation.DataBind();
        }

Answer (score 2):

Have you called DataBind() method on the object you want to be populated ?

Comment: I did call the DropDownListCities.DataBind() in Page_Load(), but nothing.

Comment: Probabily you are  calling the DataBind() before pull out the data from the Datasource. Just to check if this could be the issue try to move the .DataBind() into the Page_OnPrerender event handler